# Use composer to manage c library dependency

Tags: php, composer-php

Is there any way to use Composer to specify that a C library is a dependency and install it accordingly?

A project needs to use [php-postal](https://github.com/openvenues/php-postal), which depends on [libpostal](https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal) being available on the server. I need a reliable way to ensure that this dependency is present before requiring php-postal in composer.json.

Comment: The project you linked is a PHP extension. It needs to be compiled, which succeeds only if libpostal is present. Therefore, you can specify `"ext-php-postal": "^0.3"` and that should work. Alternatively, you can use composer's [scripts](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md) to run a command prior to installation or update that checks if a library is present (for example, by running `ldconfig -p | grep libpostal`)

Answer (score 1):

As I've just read in the composer doc, you can apparently hook into events which occur during the installation (See [Composer Scripts](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md)).

In your case the interesting event would probably be `pre-dependencies-solving`, as it is triggered before the regular dependency resolution.

As you have to check for the availability before the autoloader is generated, I would suggest using a bash script, which returns a non-zero exit code if the library is not available to interrupt the installation/updating.